# Menelaus’s theorem for vectors

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is a follow on post I made previously and thanks to the stack exchange I now know how to solve it! However, solving this using menelaus’s theorem was mentioned in the discussion but wasn’t explained, I would love to know if it is possible to solve it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying Menelaus to triangle OMB and line NA we get

$$\frac{OP}{PM}\frac{MA}{AB}\frac{BN}{NO}=1$$

$$\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{BN}{NO}=1$$

$$\frac{NO}{BN}=\frac{2}{3}$$